# Connect to Hive returned Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:777)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, hive, windows-server-2008

I have Windows 2008 Server R2 and python 3.6.
Tried to write client to DB Hive.
For begin I wrote

```
from pyhive import presto  # or import hive
cursor=presto.connect(host='namenode1', port=10000, username='tech_user', password='passsword1').cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from base1.change_cnt limit 10')
print(cursor.fetchone())
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

BUT returned error

```
  File "C:\Software\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyhive\presto.py", line 131, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Protocol must be https when passing a password")
ValueError: Protocol must be https when passing a password
```

I tried change addition attr protocol='https'

```
from pyhive import presto  # or import hive
cursor=presto.connect(host='namenode1', port=10000, protocol='https', username='tech_user', password='passsword1').cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from base1.change_cnt limit 10')
print(cursor.fetchone())
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

BUT returned another error

```
  File "C:\Software\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Software\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Software\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Software\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='namenode1', port=10000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/statement (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:777)'),))
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the server is listening SSL on port 10000 ? I bet that no. Try with your browser on https://nodename1:10000/ and let us know if it is working well.

Comment: This client can worked only HTTPS protocol? I tried write client by Java, used JDBC connect "Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://namenode1:10000/default", "tech_user", "password1");" connected OK.

Comment: This connection is not an SSL connection. Maybe SSL doesn't need to run on another port if non-SSL is not used. I advise to check their example on how to requests over SSL : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-ConnectionURLWhenSSLIsEnabledinHiveServer2